# Modify json field type via circe

Tags: json, scala, circe

I have simple Json:

```
val str = """{"test":"123"}"""
```

How I can modify `String` `"123"` to `Int` `123` to get new Json?:

```
{"test":123}
```

Now I am using:

```
val json = parse(str).getOrElse(Json.Null)
val jsObj = json.asObject.get  // Unsafe, just example
val newJson = Json.fromJsonObject(jsObj.remove("test").add("test", Json.fromInt(123)))
```

But this code is not pretty.

Is it possible to make this code prettier or maybe do it via circe optics?

Comment: You probably don't need `remove` though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should do the trick depending on how you want to manage the limit case (here I throw an exception):

```
import io.circe._
import io.circe.parser.parse

val str = """{"test":"123"}"""
val json = parse(str).getOrElse(Json.Null)
json.mapObject(
  _.mapValues( v =>
    v.asString
     .flatMap(parse(_).toOption)
     .getOrElse(throw new IllegalArgumentException("No String found"))
  )
)
```

Comment: This does not compile, but I fix it. Thanks for the idea. `json.mapObject(
    _.add("test",Json.fromInt(321)))`